# How to convert org-table to list?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I've this table:

```
|H1    |H2    |H3    |
|------+------+------|
|text11|text12|text13|
|text21|text22|text23|
|...   |...   |...   |
|textN1|textN2|textN3|
|--------------------|
```

and i want this list:

```
* text11
- H1: text11
- H2: text12
- H3: text13

* text21
- H1: text21
- H2: text22
- H3: text23

...

* textN1
- H1: textN1
- H2: textN2
- H3: textN3
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Oh this is super cool to find because I am a huge believer in having the plaintext representation of tabular data be a list of lists instead of ASCII art that looks like a table, since the latter is very painful to edit by hand and is less possible (and more complex when possible) to reflow visually to the screen size. So I would actually love an Org-mode addon where my manual editing and my saved .org files have tables written almost how you want the output in this question to look. And this makes me realize it might be possible for me to just write a bit of code to do that.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Updated code because I had misunderstood what the headings should be, and to switch to `s-join` because apparently @lap's version of Emacs doesn't have `string-join` from `subr-x` (`s-join` and `string-join` take their arguments in opposite order!).

EDIT: Last fix: OP is using an older version of Org Mode and the parsed table includes the symbol `hline` to indicate the position of horizontal lines, so we `remq` them away.

You can name the table and then use a `:var` declaration in a source
block and Org Mode will parse the table for you!

```
#+NAME: laps-table
|H1    |H2    |H3    |
|------+------+------|
|text11|text12|text13|
|text21|text22|text23|
|...   |...   |...   |
|textN1|textN2|textN3|
|--------------------|

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var tbl=laps-table
  (require 's)
  (let ((headings (car tbl)))
    (s-join
     "\n"
     (mapcar
      (lambda (row)
        (concat
         (format "* %s\n- " (car row))
         (s-join
          "\n- "
          (cl-map 'list 
                  (lambda (hd x) (concat hd ": " x))
                  headings row))))
      (remq 'hline (cdr tbl)))))
#+END_SRC
```

Running the source block results in the following:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
* text11
- H1: text11
- H2: text12
- H3: text13
* text21
- H1: text21
- H2: text22
- H3: text23
* ...
- H1: ...
- H2: ...
- H3: ...
* textN1
- H1: textN1
- H2: textN2
- H3: textN3
#+end_example
```

Comment: I've this error with your code: Symbol's function definition is void: string-join

Comment: ...not... text1, text2, etc... i want to insert text11, text21, etc. IN MY table... thanks!

Comment: `string-join` is relatively new in Emacs, if you are using an old version of Emacs you can install a library called `s` and replace `string-join` with `s-join`.

Comment: I loaded the library s.el and replaced string-join with s-join but running the code still get errors (wrong type argument: sequencep, hline)

Comment: What version of Emacs and what version of Org Mode are you using, @lap?

Comment: I forgot to mention when I said you could `s-join` that I didn't know what order it took it's arguments in, @lap. Turns out it's the opposite of `string-join`. Try the updated code. (I also fixed the headings, which, frankly I had misread from the beginning --I wrote above that you edited it, but I think you didn't: I just didn't read carefully, sorry.)

Comment: My version of Emacs is 24.3.1 and the Org version is 8.2.10. With the new version of your code... I get error: Wrong type argument: listp, hline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45931/discussion-between-lap-and-omar-antolin-camarena).